# Unity LWRP, OnPreRender, OnPostRender and OnPreCull is not called

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rendering

When using LWRP under project settings -> Grafics, OnPreRender, OnPostRender and OnPreCull is not called for any script.

```
 private void OnPreRender()
    {
        print("Working");
    }
```

Here is what happends when I switch in game: https://youtu.be/yD3uaPcnTU8

How do you get OnPreRender to work on the lightweight rendering pipline?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following code

```
RenderPipelineManager.endCameraRendering += (context, camera) =>
{
    print("Working");
};
RenderPipelineManager.endFrameRendering += (context, camera) =>
{
    print("Working");
};
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.